# ssl certificate specified in nginx virtual server not detected

Tags: nginx

I have configured my nginx virtual server as follows:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name #server_name_value;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/nginx.key;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
    }        
}
```

now for this server i have nginx.crt file, but there is another server with another configuration file for which I have another certificate.
Now i created the csr using openssl on my machine, and then verified it using tinyca2. Then I use the certificate by specifying the path.
 
Now there is another, certificate i created on the same machine, and have put both those certs in the same dir, but specified the cert to be used for a particular server.
So my question is, when I access the above server, it shows the add exception, but when i view the certificate, it doesnt use the one specified, but the other certificate I created after I created the certificate I am using above.

So is it that I can have only one certificate in the ssl dir of nginx, or is there something that i have overlooked while reading nginx docs.Because I really dont know whats happening here.

Comment: did you restart nginx after changing the configuration?

Comment: You may want to test the configuration using `nginx -T` to ensure that `nginx` is reading the configuration files you expect it to be reading.

Answer (score 0):

Does the server_name `#server_name_value` match the certificate CN in subject? If it doesn't SNI fails to match it.